# How to resolve issues with fileAttributesAtPath warning?

Tags: objective-c, ios, warnings

Now I use this code:

```
NSDictionary* attr = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileAttributesAtPath:file traverseLink:YES];
```

and get warning:

```
'fileAttributesAtPath:traverseLink:' is deprecated
```

Who knows what to use instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:` instead.

Comment: `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:` does not support symlink. So your suggestion has not the same behavior as `traverseLink:YES` from the question.

Answer (score 4):

use `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:`

```
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* attr = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:file error:&error];
```

Comment: `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:` does not support symlink. So your code has not the same behavior as `traverseLink:YES` from the question.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer forgot to handle `traverseLink:YES` from the question.

An improved answer is using both `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:` and `stringByResolvingSymlinksInPath`:

```
NSDictionary* attr = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:[file stringByResolvingSymlinksInPath] error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Special Considerations

Because this method does not return error information, it has been deprecated as of Mac OS X v10.5. **Use setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error: instead.**

[link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html)

Comment: `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:` does not support symlink. So your suggestion has not the same behavior as `traverseLink:YES` from the question.

Answer (score 0):

you should read [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/attributesOfItemAtPath%3aerror%3a):

> fileAttributesAtPath:traverseLink:
>
> Returns a dictionary that describes the POSIX attributes of the file
>   specified at a given. **(Deprecated in Mac OS X v10.5. Use
>   [attributesOfItemAtPath:error:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/attributesOfItemAtPath%3aerror%3a) instead.)**

Comment: `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:` does not support symlink. So your suggestion has not the same behavior as `traverseLink:YES` from the question.