# Warning 'fileAttributesAtPath:traverseLink is deprecated: first deprecated in ios 2.0

Tags: ios, xcode

I made this function that returns the size of file in documents directory, it works but I get warning that I wish to fix, the function:

```
-(unsigned long long int)getFileSize:(NSString*)path
{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,        NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *getFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];

NSDictionary *fileDictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileAttributesAtPath:getFilePath traverseLink:YES]; //*Warning
unsigned long long int fileSize = 0;
fileSize = [fileDictionary fileSize];

return fileSize;
}
```

*The Warning is 'fileAttributesAtPath:traverseLink: is deprecated first deprecated in ios 2.0'. What is it mean and how I can fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve issues with fileAttributesAtPath warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019353/how-to-resolve-issues-with-fileattributesatpath-warning)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In most cases, when you get a report about a deprecated method, you look it up in the reference docs and it will tell you what replacement to use.

> **fileAttributesAtPath:traverseLink:**
>   Returns a dictionary that describes the POSIX attributes of the file specified at a given. (Deprecated in iOS 2.0. Use attributesOfItemAtPath:error: instead.)

So use `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:` instead.

Here's the simple way:

```
NSDictionary *fileDictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:getFilePath error:nil];
```

The more complete way is:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *fileDictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:getFilePath error:&error];
if (fileDictionary) {
    // make use of attributes
} else {
    // handle error found in 'error'
}
```

Edit: In case you don't know what *deprecated* means, it means that the method or class is now obsolete. You should use a newer API to perform a similar action.

Comment: Can you please give me an example how to use attributesOfItemAtPath:error:

Comment: It's virtually identical to what you are using. You can pass `nil` for the `error:` parameter to get started quickly.

Comment: `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:` does not support symlink. So your code has not the same behavior as `traverseLink:YES` from the question.

Comment: @Cœur The documentation states to use `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:` in place of `fileAttributesAtPath:traverseLink:`. The docs for `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:` provide info on how to deal with symbolic links.

Comment: @rmaddy not really, the doc for `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:` does not provide a clear solution. See my answer for how to solve it.

Comment: The `stringByResolvingSymlinksInPath` method in your new answer is exactly what I'm talking about. It is mentioned in the docs for `attributesOfItemAtPath`.

Comment: @rmaddy, you're right! I couldn't find it because I happened to read doc for `attributesOfFileSystemForPath:error:` instead of `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:`.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer forgot to handle `traverseLink:YES` from the question.

An improved answer is using both `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:` and `stringByResolvingSymlinksInPath`:

```
NSString *fullPath = [getFilePath stringByResolvingSymlinksInPath];
NSDictionary *fileDictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:fullPath error:nil];
```